# Meaning of ls -l output in links field

Tags: command-line

My output of `ls -l` is:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 dario dario 4096 Sep 14 13:15 d1
-rw-r--r-- 1 dario dario    0 Sep 14 13:18 file1
```

Why are `files = 1`?

d1 is empty. Why show `2`?

Answer (score 2):

The number `1` for `file1` says there's no another hardlink to this file. If you `unlink` or `rm` this `file1` in the current directory then its content will be marked as free space on disk and eventually overwritten. If there were two other hardlinks then the total number would be `3` and this is what you would see.

The number `2` for directory `d1` is somewhat similar. In Linux you cannot freely create hardlinks to directories, yet (almost) every directory has at least two:

- its "name" in its parent directory (`d1` in this case),
- `.` in itself;
- *additionally* `..` in each of its subdirectories (there are none in this case).

Note that `..` in `d1` itself *doesn't* contribute to this number. It contributes to the link count of the parent directory of `d1`.

The exception is `/`. It has no parent directory but `.` *and* `..` in `/` refer to `/`, so still you have two links plus one for every subdirectory.

This is how it works in `ext` family filesystem. Other filesystems may behave differently. E.g. `btrfs` commonly shows `1` for directories.

Comment: Excellent, thanks: you have corrected a common misconception.

Answer (score 0):

Every directory contains at least two entries. These are:

`.` (current directory) and,

`..` (parent directory).

`file1` has one link pointing to it